# How to get exact value of a token with Web3.py on PancakeSwap? Function getAmountsOut() returns a wrong value

Tags: python, web3py, binance-smart-chain, pancakeswap

I was trying to get the price of various crypto coins using web3.py.

```
tokenAddres = '0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82' #Cake
tokenAddres = Web3.toChecksumAddress(tokenAddres)
bnbPrice = calcBNBPrice()
print(f'current BNB price: {bnbPrice}')
priceInBnb = calcSell(1, tokenAddres)
print(f'SHIT_TOKEN VALUE IN BNB : {priceInBnb} | Just convert it to USD ')
print(f'SHIT_TOKEN VALUE IN USD: {priceInBnb * bnbPrice}')
```

The calcsell function should be the one that return the value of the token in BNB

```
def calcSell(tokenToSell, tokenAddress):
    BNBTokenAddress = Web3.toChecksumAddress("0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c")  # BNB
    amountOut = None

    tokenRouter = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(tokenAddress), abi=tokenAbi)
    tokenDecimals = tokenRouter.functions.decimals().call()
    tokenToSell = setDecimals(tokenToSell, tokenDecimals) # Set token a correct number of 0s
    
    router = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(pancakeSwapContract), abi=pancakeSwapAbi)
    amountIn = web3.toWei(tokenToSell, 'ether')
    amountOut = router.functions.getAmountsOut(amountIn, [tokenAddress, BNBTokenAddress]).call()
    amountOut = web3.fromWei(amountOut[1], 'ether')

    return amountOut
```

The value I get is:

```
SHIT_TOKEN VALUE IN BNB : 974136.205251839691973598 | Just convert it to USD 
SHIT_TOKEN VALUE IN USD: 340708627.4489159379891912819
```

while the correct one is:

```
SHIT_TOKEN VALUE IN BNB : 0.048846069961106416 | Just convert it to USD 
SHIT_TOKEN VALUE IN USD: 16.98585439310707
```

Any guess?

Answer (score 6):

I know of two ways to get a price quote from PancakeSwap using web3.py:

1. Using [their API](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-info-api/blob/develop/v2-documentation.md).

```
import requests

def calcSell(tokenAddress):
    apiURL = "https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/"
    response = requests.get(url = apiURL + tokenAddress)
    price = extractPriceFromRaw(response)
    return price

def extractPriceFromRaw(response):
    jsonRaw = response.json()
    price = jsonRaw['data']['price']
    return price

CAKE = '0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82'
print(calcSell(KRW))
```

2. Using their smart contract's .getAmountsOut() function directly. What you are trying to do.

```
from web3 import Web3

def calcSell(tokenAddress):
    routerContract = web3.eth.contract(address=routerPCS, abi=pancakeSwapAbi)
    oneToken = web3.toWei(1, 'Ether')
    price = routerContract.functions.getAmountsOut(oneToken, [tokenAddress, BUSD]).call()
    normalizedPrice = web3.fromWei(price[1], 'Ether')
    return normalizedPrice

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443'))
routerPCS = '0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E'
BUSD = '0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56'
CAKE = '0x0E09FaBB73Bd3Ade0a17ECC321fD13a19e81cE82'
print(calcSell(CAKE))
```

I did not try to debug your code, but I assume that your problems are because of the way you torture `tokenToSell` value, instead of simply making it equal to 1 Ether: `tokenToSell = web3.toWei(1, 'Ether')`

Comment: how can i find the value for pancakeSwapAbi?

Comment: @BjkOcean, ABI's are usually published together with the contract source code. For PancakeSwap - it can be found on [BSCscan](https://bscscan.com/address/0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e#code), below contract's source code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line

`tokenToSell = setDecimals(tokenToSell, tokenDecimals) # Set token a correct number of 0s`

does the exact same thing as this line

`amountIn = web3.toWei(tokenToSell, 'ether')`

which makes the `amountIn` to be `1*(10**18)*(10**18)`
Assuming the decimal is 18, get rid of `amountIn = web3.toWei(tokenToSell, 'ether')` as tokenToSell is already in it's wei format.

Answer (score 0):

The exact price of the token can be retrieved via the LP pair contract.
For example Here Is A Random ShitCoin LP Contract: https://bscscan.com/address/0xeb821dcc4903935adfc0d52fa2155ab281fbf99b#code

[image]

The lp pair contract contains the base and quote token for the pair, so now you can calculate the price via this!

Price: 1024.2289 / 11225747.7426 => 0.00009123925 BNB

**Bonus**

If you want to fetch the token lp pair contract automatically there is a function named getPair(tokenA, tokenB) in pancakeswap factory v2 which can be used to fetch the pair, ex: getPair(randomshitcoin, wbnbaddress), getPair(randomshitcoin, usdtaddress)

Answer (score -2):

use this api
https://docs.moralis.io/

you can easily get token price with WEB3API

```
    Moralis.initialize("APPID");

    Moralis.serverURL = 'https://serverlink'
    const options = {
        address: "token address",
        chain: "bsc",
        exchange: "PancakeSwapv2"
    };

    Moralis.Web3API.token.getTokenPrice(options).then((result: String) => {
        
  
        const userStr = JSON.stringify(result);

        JSON.parse(userStr, (key, value) => {
            
          if ( key === "usdPrice") {

              console.log(value)
              settokenprice(value)
          }
          return value;
      });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).